# NSTimer Swift difficulty

Tags: swift, nstimer

I am trying to create a NSTimer so that I can move a UIImageView down but
The NSTImer is having difficulty, saying first that this.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target:self(), selector: Selector ("mrockdown"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

is missing argument for parameter #1 in call. But when I remove the brackets from the `target:self()` it tells me

> Cannot invoke 'scheduledTimerWIthTimerInterval' with an argument list of type '(Double, target: ViewController -> () -> ViewController, selector: Selector, userinfo: nil, repeates Bool.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with *where* you are saying this. It looks like you are trying to say this as part of a property declaration:

```
class ViewController {
    var timer = ...
    // ...
}
```

But you can't do that, because there is no `self` as far as a stored property is concerned. You need to declare the timer as an Optional and then initialize it later:

```
class ViewController {
    var timer = NSTimer!
    func someMethod {
        timer = ...
    }
}
```

Then you will remove the parentheses (they are wrong) and everything will compile just fine.

Comment: However, you should _not_ be using a repeating timer just to do animation. If you are, stop. Instead, use _animation_. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside the function where you want to trigger the timer (i.e. `viewDidLoad` or some `IBAction`)

```
 _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: yourInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(yourFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

That being said, to animate a view you should use this instead:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: yourDuration) {
    // set yourView's final position here
}
```